# Determine the probability that the number of digits 5 in a random 5-digit number is at least 3

Tags: python, combinatorics

need yours help i tried to find any examples but i couldn't find it

im poor in using combinatoric so i'm stuck here and i have no idea how to do this task
Determine the probability that the number of digits 5 in a random 5-digit number is at least 3

Comment: That's a math question, not a computer programming question. Do you know what a binomial distribution is?

Comment: i need to do it in python

Comment: This is extremely not clear (1) what does python have to do with your question? (2) what have you tried **exactly**?

Comment: i have to write program which solve this task

Comment: 5 digit range is easily iteratable, write a for loop over the whole range, check if each value has at least 3 5 digits and add those up, the probality will be those that have at least 3 5 digits / total number of five digit numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your probability distribution.  If you are looking a the simple ratio of 5 digit numbers with with at least 3 5s, then it's simply a matter of counting.  If you want the statistical probability in real world situation you should look into [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law#Generalization_to_digits_beyond_the_first).

To simply count, you can go "brute force" (because there aren't that many 5 digit numbers):

```
eligible = sum(str(N).count("5")>=3 for N in range(10000,100000))  #819
probability = eligible / 90000

print(probability) # 0.0091
```